# Symfony2.3 - Web Profiler not displayed on error

Tags: debugging, symfony, profiler

I have a problem while working in the dev environnement of my Symfony 2.3 project.

The profiler works great in the debug toolbar, but when I have an error with my code, I dont get the usual Symfony profiler message but only the browser 500 message ("Server Error" on Chrome and a blank page on Firefox)

I have to read the apache error.log file to get the error message everytime I want to know what happened.

Here is the content of my config_dev.yml file :

```
imports:
- { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type:  firephp
            level: info
        chromephp:
            type:  chromephp
            level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

And my app_dev.php file :

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
   || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
   || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
   header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
   exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Where should I start looking ?

---

Comment: Have you had a look at this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705368/make-chrome-display-pages-even-on-500-or-404-codes-behave-like-firefox

Answer (score 3):

I found answer!

in symfony 2.3:

The debugging tools are not enabled by default anymore and should be added to the web/app_dev.php

detailed here https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/UPGRADE-2.3.md