# Make Chrome display pages even on 500 or 404 codes (behave like Firefox)

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, symfony

We're developing a new site in Symfony.  When Symfony encounters an error, such as a "no route found", and debug is set to true, it not only outputs a 404 code, it actually shows the error on the page.  Firefox displays what the server returned, but Chrome does not.

For my no route found example:

Firefox shows this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Fb5.png
Chrome shows this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCDOm.png

Is there a way to get Chrome to behave like Firefox under these conditions?

Edit:  There seems to be some questioning of what's actually happening.  I don't know what's causing this, otherwise I would fix it.  Here's what I see in the Chrome network inspector  (note that this image is for a 500 error, but the same happens with 404's): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDWlU.png

Notice the content length of zero.  If I go to the exact same URL through Firefox (same server, everything), it shows the actual Symfony error.

Comment: can you provide information what the devtools netpanel says about your response? is there any , if yes can you inspect it ? looking at the upvotes there seem to be many people experiencing this ... but in my past 2 years of symfony2 using chrome i never had this happen to me - symfony's debug output was always delivered :/

Comment: Updated with a little more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the monolog config in your config_dev.yml, remove the firephp/chromephp sections.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 That is interesting. Very strange behaviour. I'm assuming once [PR569](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/pull/569) is released this shouldn't be a problem in the future. I'm glad you got it sorted out though.

Answer (score 6):

There is a bug report raised for this:

> [Issue 1695](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1695): Chrome needs option to turn off "Friendly 404" displays

According to the comments on that issue, if the server error page is more than 512 bytes, then it gets displayed correctly.

That said, I can't actually reproduce the problem, so I'm not sure if that workaround actually fixes it.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 What OS are you using? And do you have an example of a link that demonstrates the problem? I'm curious why I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Windows 7.  The link is not public, we have debug turned on on our local dev environments.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Well if you go to a random link like http://www.google.com/badlink do you have the same problem? I'm trying to establish if it happens to you on all 404 pages, or there is something specific about your error pages that triggers the issue.

Comment: If I go there, I see the Google 404 with the robot.  I don't know what specifically causes it.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Having looking at the updated information in your question, I have now been able to reproduce the problem. It seems those custom messages are shown when the response from the server is completely blank. The question then is why your server is returned a zero length response to Chrome but not Firefox. I'd be curious to see what happens if you get Chrome to fake Firefox's User-Agent header. I believe there are Chrome extensions that can do that.

Comment: Wow.  Thought you were totally off base and I was going to come back with "that's ridiculous".  SURE ENOUGH.  The Symfony error pages return differently based on the user agent string.  What a pile of crap.  I set the UAS to Firefox 10, worked fine.  Set back to Chrome, had problems again.

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8413  Looks like this is exactly the issue.